# How to filter an json object by another object - Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

How can I filter a json object with another object in Javascript (cannot use JQuery)

This is my JSON object

```
var jsondata = [
  {
    "firstName": "Sam",
    "lastName": "Jones",
    "age": "10"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sam1",
    "lastName": "Jones1",
    "age": "10"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sam2",
    "lastName": "Jones2",
    "age": "12"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sam3",
    "lastName": "Jones3",
    "age": "13"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sam4",
    "lastName": "Jones4",
    "age": "14"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sam5",
    "lastName": "Jones5",
    "age": "15"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sam",
    "lastName": "Jones11",
    "age": "16"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sam6",
    "lastName": "Jones6",
    "age": "17"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sam7",
    "lastName": "Jones7",
    "age": "18"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sam8",
    "lastName": "Jones8",
    "age": "19"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sam9",
    "lastName": "Jones9",
    "age": "20"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sam10",
    "lastName": "Jones10",
    "age": "21"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sam11",
    "lastName": "Jones11",
    "age": "22"
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sam12",
    "lastName": "Jones12",
    "age": "23"
  }
]
```

The above is the filterable object, now below is the object for filtering

```
var filterArray = [{"id":"firstName","value":["Sam"]},{"id":"lastName","value":["Jones"]}]
```

I need to check the the fields of json object (jsondata) like firstName, lastName and match the values of both objects.

Suppose firstname field of jsondata will be compared with id of filterArray and their values will be matched. Alongside lastname will also be compared.

FInally I want to store the filtered object (after eliminating those which are not in filter in a variable). How can I realize this functionality? Please help.

I need to implement this using plain JS, I cannot use Jquery.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: I cannot understand how to implement this. That is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to make a boolean value that will work with `filter()`.

For example:

```js
var jsondata = [{"firstName": "Sam","lastName": "Jones","age": "10"},{"firstName": "Sam1","lastName": "Jones1","age": "10"},{"firstName": "Sam2","lastName": "Jones2","age": "12"},{"firstName": "Sam3","lastName": "Jones3","age": "13"},{"firstName": "Sam4","lastName": "Jones4","age": "14"},{"firstName": "Sam5","lastName": "Jones5","age": "15"},{"firstName": "Sam","lastName": "Jones11","age": "16"},{"firstName": "Sam6","lastName": "Jones6","age": "17"},{"firstName": "Sam7","lastName": "Jones7","age": "18"},{"firstName": "Sam8","lastName": "Jones8","age": "19"},{"firstName": "Sam9","lastName": "Jones9","age": "20"},{"firstName": "Sam10","lastName": "Jones10","age": "21"},{"firstName": "Sam11","lastName": "Jones11","age": "22"},{"firstName": "Sam12","lastName": "Jones12","age": "23"}]
  
var filterArray = [{"id":"firstName","value":["Sam"]},{"id":"lastName","value":["Jones"]}]

let filtered = jsondata.filter(item =>        // filter jsondata
       filterArray.every( f =>                // so every member of filter array
            f.value.includes(item[f.id])) )   // has a corresponding item[id] in value

console.log(filtered)
```

The above filter says that for `every` item in `filterArray` you want the `value` array to include the item keyed to `id`. This will make it so the item in `jsondata` needs to match all the criteria in `filterArray`. If you add `Sam1` and `Jones1` to the arrays, you'll get two items in the filter.

```js
var jsondata = [{"firstName": "Sam","lastName": "Jones","age": "10"},{"firstName": "Sam1","lastName": "Jones1","age": "10"},{"firstName": "Sam2","lastName": "Jones2","age": "12"},{"firstName": "Sam3","lastName": "Jones3","age": "13"},{"firstName": "Sam4","lastName": "Jones4","age": "14"},{"firstName": "Sam5","lastName": "Jones5","age": "15"},{"firstName": "Sam","lastName": "Jones11","age": "16"},{"firstName": "Sam6","lastName": "Jones6","age": "17"},{"firstName": "Sam7","lastName": "Jones7","age": "18"},{"firstName": "Sam8","lastName": "Jones8","age": "19"},{"firstName": "Sam9","lastName": "Jones9","age": "20"},{"firstName": "Sam10","lastName": "Jones10","age": "21"},{"firstName": "Sam11","lastName": "Jones11","age": "22"},{"firstName": "Sam12","lastName": "Jones12","age": "23"}]
  
var filterArray = [{"id":"firstName","value":["Sam", "Sam1"]},{"id":"lastName","value":["Jones", "Jones1"]}]

let filtered = jsondata.filter(item =>        // filter jsondata
       filterArray.every( f =>                // so every member of filter array
            f.value.includes(item[f.id])) )   // has a corresponding item[id] in value

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

If any of the conditions in the filterArray are false then it will return false, otherwise it will return true. Array.prototype.filter() will create a new array with items for which the function returned true.

```js
const jsondata = jsondata=[{firstName:"Sam",lastName:"Jones",age:"10"},{firstName:"Sam1",lastName:"Jones1",age:"10"},{firstName:"Sam2",lastName:"Jones2",age:"12"},{firstName:"Sam3",lastName:"Jones3",age:"13"},{firstName:"Sam4",lastName:"Jones4",age:"14"},{firstName:"Sam5",lastName:"Jones5",age:"15"},{firstName:"Sam",lastName:"Jones11",age:"16"},{firstName:"Sam6",lastName:"Jones6",age:"17"},{firstName:"Sam7",lastName:"Jones7",age:"18"},{firstName:"Sam8",lastName:"Jones8",age:"19"},{firstName:"Sam9",lastName:"Jones9",age:"20"},{firstName:"Sam10",lastName:"Jones10",age:"21"},{firstName:"Sam11",lastName:"Jones11",age:"22"},{firstName:"Sam12",lastName:"Jones12",age:"23"}];

const filterArray = [{"id":"firstName","value":["Sam"]},{"id":"lastName","value":["Jones"]}];

var match = jsondata.filter(function(element){

    for(let i=0; i<filterArray.length; i++){
        if(!filterArray[i].value.includes(element[filterArray[i].id])){
            return false
        }
    }

    return true;

});

console.log(match);
```

Comment: Why is this returning `Sam1` `Jones1` when the `Sam` `Jones` is in the array?

Comment: @MarkMeyer fixed